# Is there a javascript controls library which has outlook.com (metro) "look and feel" and functionality?

Tags: javascript, web-controls

I am looking for outlook.com`s javascript web controls library. I mean the library analog of Yahoo UI or Google GWT with which outlook.com is built. I look for such a js control library that can help me build metro style js web apps. Is there such a thing?

Are these controls from system.ui.web.webcontrols namespace or just Ajax Control Toolkit? I think so because outlook.com pages end on aspx.

Comment: What makes you think that outlook.com is based on public libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first result on google when searching for *JavaScript Metro Interface* seems to be what you're looking for. 
[Source can be found on github](https://github.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS)
[This might also be worth a look](http://www.noupe.com/css/metro-ui-css-own-tiled-website-71225.html)(second result)
[MSDN has some pages on this, too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465165.aspx) - haven't looked at these, yet

Comment: Thanks. The first two are the same - olton metro ui.